# Emberjs making 2 simultaneous requests

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

My `router.js` file is like this:

```
  this.route('cards', function() {
    this.route('all');
    this.route('card', {path: '/:card_id'}, function() {
      this.route('edit');
    });
    this.route('new');
  });
```

In `all.js`, I've:

```
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('card');
  }
```

In `cards.js`, I've:

```
  beforeModel() {
    this.transitionTo('cards.all');
  },

  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('card');
  }
```

As you can see that I'm making 2 requests which, IMO, is not necessary. So, if I remove the call from `cards.js`, the `new.js` doesn't work properly.

When I create a new card from `new.js`, after creation, it should go to `/cards/1` and show the proper data. But, when I remove that line from `cards.js`, after creation of a card, it goes to `/cards/1` but the data is not saved.

Link to repo: https://github.com/ghoshnirmalya/hub-client

Comment: `this.store.findAll` is cached by ember-data so its not a problem. To tell you wats wrong with your `new` route you have to show us your  code.

Comment: i've attached the link to the repo.

Comment: Hm, everything looks good except one thing: Why do you call the `transitionTo` in `beforeModel` of `cards.js`? This *should* be in `cards/index.js`. Otherwise it gets called when you deep-link into `cards.all`.

Comment: i don't have a `cards/index.js`. should i create one?

Comment: Exactly. If you are in a route that has nested routes you are always in the  `index` route if you are not explicit in another child route. So you want to redirect from the `index` to the `all` route. Or use the `index` as the `all` route.